# Showing and hiding header nav in Mean.js app

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I am building a blog with the [Yeoman Mean.js generator](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs).  So far I am really enjoying working with Mean.js, however I am relatively new to Angular development, so some things just don't click for me yet.

I would like to hide the header on all pages of my app, and only show it if I am logged in.  I'll be pulling signup out of the header, and logging in from a single location to manage my blog.

I tried using `ng-show="topbarActive"` on the `<header>` element present in the /app/views/layout.server.view.html:

```
<header ng-show="topbarActive" data-ng-include="'/modules/core/views/header.client.view.html'" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default"></header>
```

I then tried explicitly setting this variable to `false` in */public/modules/core/controllers/home.client.controller.js*:

`$scope.topbarActive = false;`

I set this value to `true` in */public/modules/users/controllers/authentication.client.controller.js*, in the hopes that I could manually ping http://localhost:3000/#!/signup and see my header bar.

After this set up I do not see the header anywhere.  Seeing as how I am new to 'The Angular Way', what steps am I missing in order to achieve the behavior I am looking for.  Am I confused in how Mean.js builds it's dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the key concepts in AngularJS is scoping. In this particular case your controller HomeController is assigned to the first div *under* the header. That makes HomeController scope unavailable to it's parent (header) which actually doesn't have any controller at all.

To make your configuration work, please add a new controller, for example:

```
/* /public/modules/core/controllers/body.client.controller.js */
'use strict';

angular.module('core').controller('BodyController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'Menus',
    function($scope, Authentication, Menus) {
        $scope.topbarActive = true;
    }]);
```

And then add this controller to the body in layout.server.view.html:

```
<body ng-cloak ng-controller="BodyController">
```

Alternatively you can create a controller for your  tag only, depends on where you're going from here.

Comment: I knew it would be something pretty straightforward like that.  Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction!